# Query in Hibernate using UserType column does not make conversion using nullSafeSet

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

In some legacy code I am working with, I have an Hibernate model containing a UserType attribute, to represent a boolean using integers for indexing. In addition, it stores 'false' as null for Oracle optimization.

```
/**
 * Data type for a boolean value stored in a NUMBER oracle column. 1 evaluates
 * to true, null evaluates to false.
 * 
 * This is designed for oracle indexing, since null values are not indexed.
 * 
 * 
 */

public class BooleanUserType implements UserType {
    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.INTEGER };

    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    public Class<?> returnedClass() {
        return Boolean.class;
    }

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Boolean result = false;
        resultSet.getInt(names[0]);
        if (!resultSet.wasNull()) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Boolean input = (Boolean) value;
        if (input == null || input == false) {
            preparedStatement.setNull(index, Types.INTEGER);

        } else {
            preparedStatement.setInt(index, 1);
        }
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y)
            return true;
        if (null == x || null == y)
            return false;
        return x.equals(y);
    }
```

This BooleanUserType is used as a column for this (edited) model:

```
public class CustomString implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5311205585865001342L;

  @Id
  @Column(name="custom_string_id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="text")
  private String text;

  @Column(name="active")
  @Type(type="my.org.BooleanUserType")  // store false as 'null' -- an Oracle optimization
  private Boolean active;

  (...)
```

According to [this StackOverflow reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1475437)

> nullSafeSet is invoked both when the entity is being saved / updated
>   and when query parameter has to be set

However, this is not the behaviour I am observing, as when I query for this model using a Boolean for the `active` column, the conversion is not made and I don't get the expected results.

I have a CustomString object saved on the DB:

```
new CustomString(1, "text", Boolean.FALSE);
```

I make the query that does not work as I would expect:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(CustomString.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("active", Boolean.FALSE));
c.list() // No results!
```

If I do this instead, it works:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(CustomString.class);
c.add(Restrictions.isNull("active"));
c.list() // Expected result!
```

Also saving the object with `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `FALSE`, and then querying for `TRUE`, works fine.

I have added some debug log lines in my `nullSafeSet` method and I can verify it is not called when making the query.

Should `nullSafeSet` be actually called by Hibernate and somehow not working as expected, or I there is something I am missing and I should approach this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying logic `nullSafeSet()` logic will only be evaluated when actually flushing objects to the DB in insert/update scenarios. When building up a `Critera` query, Hibernate will use the `@Column` annotation to determine column names but will not automatically flip "`= FALSE`" to "`is null`" for you.

More precisely, the `SELECT` portion of the query is per-determined by the `@Columns` defined in your class, so Hibernate will always run:

```
SELECT custom_string_id, text, active FROM [schema].[table_name]
```

Adding `Restrictions` to your `Criteria` will augment there `WHERE` predicate, but it will not leverage your `BooleanUserType` logic until AFTER it gets back rows to be parsed into instances of your entity.

Finally, I'm not sure which Oracle optimization you were referring to, but if you're trying to leverage the fact that null values drop out of indexes, then you may not want to query for `NULL` instead of `False` as it would run a full table scan. If, however, you only ever cared about the active (`True`) rows and you wanted to effectively deprecate/archive inactive rows, then your approach of setting the old data to `NULL` would indeed get you the index performance gains you're referring to.

Comment: what about using a custom type instead? http://learningviacode.blogspot.ie/2011/09/creating-hibernate-custom-type-2.html

Comment: I don't have high hopes for that, but you may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145693/custom-like-predicate-to-handle-custom-user-defined-types-hibernate-usertype